# Exo Smart R9 F2445 wifi card not detected

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless

I've just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my eExo Smart R9 F2445 laptop, which came with Windows 10. The problem is that Ubuntu doesn't find any wifi network. It doesn't even give  me the option of enabling wifi. Bluetooth works fine, but wifi isn't there.

I tried installing the Windows driver with ndiswrapper, but it's still not working.

I wrote `lshw -C network` on the terminal and it output:

```
 descripción: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       fabricante: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:02:00.0
       nombre lógico: ens1
       versión: 0c
       serie: b0:25:aa:1f:fb:16
       tamaño: 100Mbit/s
       capacidad: 1Gbit/s
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuración: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 ip=192.168.1.36 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       recursos: irq:310 ioport:e000(size=256) memoria:81200000-81200fff memoria:a0000000-a0003fff
```

Results of `lspci -knn` :

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register [8086:2280] (rev 35)
    Subsystem: Device [1d05:1012]
    Kernel driver in use: iosf_mbi_pci
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:22b1] (rev 35)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Device [1d05:1012]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:13.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SATA Controller [8086:22a3] (rev 35)
    Subsystem: Device [1d05:1012]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller [8086:22b5] (rev 35)
    Subsystem: Device [1d05:1012]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:1a.0 Encryption controller [1080]: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine [8086:2298] (rev 35)
    Subsystem: Device [1d05:1012]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_txe
    Kernel modules: mei_txe
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller [8086:2284] (rev 35)
    Subsystem: Device [1d05:1012]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #1 [8086:22c8] (rev 35)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #2 [8086:22ca] (rev 35)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU [8086:229c] (rev 35)
    Subsystem: Device [1d05:1012]
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx SMBus Controller [8086:2292] (rev 35)
    Subsystem: Device [1d05:1012]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Device [1d05:1012]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

---

```
$lsusb: 

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:b720 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please run `sudo update-pciids` then try the `lspci` command.

Comment: Hi, this is what came out:
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)

Comment: Use the following command : `sudo apt install wget curl` then `sudo update-pciids` , please run `lspci -knn` or `lspci -nn` as mentioned @karel

Comment: Donde.  The result is now on the question.

Comment: Hi, i've just added lsusb to the question. Thanks to all for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wireless device is this:

> 0bda:b720 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.

It uses the driver rtl8723bu. I will propose a method to install the driver and, if successful, amend it a bit to avoid recompiling the driver after every kernel upgrade.

Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723bu.git
cd rtl8723bu
nano Makefile
```

Find the line at about line 21 that reads:

```
EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DCONFIG_CONCURRENT_MODE
```

Comment it out with the symbol # so that it now reads:

```
#EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DCONFIG_CONCURRENT_MODE
```

Save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and close (Ctrl+x) the text editor.

Now proceed:

```
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8723bu
```

Is your wireless working?

**EDIT**: You will have compiled the driver for your currently running kernel only. When Update Manager installs a later kernel version, also known as linux-image, after the request reboot, recompile:

```
cd rtl8723bu
make clean
make
sudo make install 
sudo modprobe 8723bu
```

Please retain the file and these instructions for that time.

**EDIT2**: To get the module to load automagically on boot, please do:

```
echo 8723bu | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. I did what you said and now wifi is working. The problem i have now is that it stops working after i reboot my pc. I have to use the modprobe command every time to get it working. Do you know what can i do to make it work automatically?

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few minutes.

Comment: It doesn't stop working after a kernel update, it stops working after every reboot i make. I've done what you've said on the edit and it's still not working. Is there a way to make it work without having to use the modprobe every time i reboot? Thanks.

Comment: Please see my next edit!

Comment: Now it's working! Thank you very much for the help!!

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: Done!  Sorry, i’m new at this. Thank you very much!